# Observable.bindCallback only returns value if I subscribe to it directly

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Observable.bindCallback only returns value if I subscribe to it directly
in other words, this works fine:

```
return this.store.select(store => store.appDb.appBaseUrl)
            .take(1)
            .mergeMap(baseUrl => {
                const url = `${baseUrl}?command=GetCustomers&resellerUserName=aaa&resellerPassword=bbbb`;
                return this.http.get(url)
                    .map(res => {
                        var xmlData = res.text()
                        const boundCallback = Observable.bindCallback(this.processXml, (xmlData: any) => xmlData);
                        return boundCallback(this, xmlData)
                            .subscribe((x) => {
                                return x;
                            });
                    })
            })
```

however I need to avoid the subscription as I am running inside `@effect` which auto subscribes for me, so I run:

```
return this.store.select(store => store.appDb.appBaseUrl)
            .take(1)
            .mergeMap(baseUrl => {
                const url = `${baseUrl}?command=GetCustomers&resellerUserName=aaa&resellerPassword=aaa`;
                return this.http.get(url)
                    .map(res => {
                        var xmlData = res.text()
                        const boundCallback = Observable.bindCallback(this.processXml, (xmlData: any) => xmlData);
                        var d:any = boundCallback(this, xmlData)
                        return d;
                    }).map(d=>{console.log(d)})
            })
```

but instead of getting a value now I am getting a:

and this is d:

[image]

regards

Sean

Comment: What is this supposed to do anyway? Do you really want to return an `Observable` or `Subscription` from `map()` operator? Statement `return x;` inside `subscribe()` does nothing.

Comment: I need to return the value, this.processXml takes a callback and value and returns the result. I tried with a promise and getting a PromiseObservable, but not getting the value :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do it should look something like this (obviously I didn't test it):

```
return this.store.select(store => store.appDb.appBaseUrl)
            .take(1)
            .mergeMap(baseUrl => {
                const url = `${baseUrl}?command=GetCustomers&resellerUserName=aaa&resellerPassword=aaa`;
                return this.http.get(url)
                    .mergeMap(res => {
                        var xmlData = res.text()
                        const boundCallback = Observable.bindCallback(this.processXml, (xmlData: any) => xmlData);
                        return boundCallback(this, xmlData)
                    }).do(d => console.log(d))
            })
```

I used `mergeMap()` because I want to get the value from the Observable returned by `boundCallback()`.

Also when using `map()` you **always need to return a value** that is propagated further. In your example you're not returning anything so you can use just `do()` to see print what values go through.

Edit:

So this is a simplified version of what you're trying to do.

```
class A {
    private processXml(context, xmlData, cb) {
        context.parseString(xmlData, {attrkey: 'attr'}, function (err, result) {
            if (err || !result) return cb(null); return cb(result);
        })
    }

    private parseString(str, _, cb) {
        return cb(null, str);
    }

    private mockHttpGet() {
        return Rx.Observable.of({
            text: () => {
                return 'abc';
            }
        });
    }

    test() {
        return this.mockHttpGet()
            .mergeMap(res => {
                var xmlData = res.text();
                const boundCallback = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(this.processXml, (xmlData: any) => xmlData);
                return boundCallback(this, xmlData)
            }).do(d => console.log(d))
    }
}

let a = new A();
a.test().subscribe(val => console.log('subscribed result', val));
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/reweraw/2/edit?js,console

This demo prints:

```
abc
subscribe abc
```

The `BoundCallbackObservable` (and this applies to operators as well) do nothing until you subscribe to them. That's why in the debugger you see just raw data.

My demo works as you probably want so check out how am I using `mergeMap()` to get the actual value from the nested Observable and try to replicate the same logic in you application.

Comment: tx for the reply, but I get a null on ```d``` :(

Comment: @born2net Then check what `processXml` method returns and what input it receives. Btw, you don't need to use `Observable.bindCallback` at all and just return `this.processXml(xmlData)` (or whatever you use it for)

Comment: but this.processXml(xmlData) is not my function, and it takes a callback

Comment: So how do you use it? and why it takes `this` as a parameter?

Comment: tx for the replies, here is processXml ```private processXml(context, xmlData, cb) {
        context.parseString(xmlData, {attrkey: 'attr'}, function (err, result) {
            if (err || !result)
                return cb(null);
            return cb(result);
        })

    }```

Comment: if u dont mind standby, I am making a video to show the issue

Comment: first of all a BIG tx for the time.. BIG. And I was able to solve it as I was one Obs too deep, honestly I am not sure why I had to put two flatMaps instead of just one (tried and 2 did it) you can see my answer above! TX again...

Answer (score 0):

found the solution, I was one Obs too deep:

```
return this.store.select(store => store.appDb.appBaseUrl)
            .take(1)
            .mergeMap(baseUrl => {
                const url = `${baseUrl}?command=GetCustomers&resellerUserName=reseller@ms.com&resellerPassword=XXXX`;
                return this.http.get(url)
                    .map(res => {
                        return res.text()
                    }).flatMap(jData=>{
                        const boundCallback = Observable.bindCallback(this.processXml, (xmlData: any) => xmlData);
                        return boundCallback(this, jData)
                    }).map(businessData=>{
                        return businessData;
                    })
            })
```